# Connotation of 親密 (shinmitsu)

Tags: words, anime, connotation

jisho.org translates shinmitsu as "intimacy; friendship​", and says it's a common word. But I want to know its connotation. Is it heavily inclined to romance? Or heavily inclined towards a platonic bond? Or completely neutral between those two extremes? Can it be used to refer to a parent's bond with their child? etc.

For context, I encountered it in the gotoubun no hanayome movie (a harem anime). 「私とあなた達、どちらがより親密なのか？」 (It's a question of, between me and you guys, who are more shinmitsu [with MC-kun]).

Answer (score 3):

An especially close relationship that could be romantic, platonic, or familial. I think it as a step up from 仲がいい.

One could argue that by avoiding saying 恋愛関係 and the like, it implies something decidedly not romance, but I don't think that that interpretation is so definitive.